# WorkManager WorkName table not being cleared after jobs complete

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm using WorkManager by calling `WorkManager.enqueueUniqueWork(String, ExistingWorkPolicy, OneTimeWorkRequest)`, I examined on the db on disk `androix.work.workdb` and noticed in the `WorkName` table there is an entry for each job I started. They aren't removed after the work completed. Is this normal? Will they automatically be cleared? When and by whom? (the system or WorkManager?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. WorkManager keeps finished jobs in its database so that you can continue to query for its `WorkInfo` via [`getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData(java.lang.String)) or other methods that give you the stats back (a fact pointed out by the [`keepResultsForAtLeast()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest.Builder.html#keepResultsForAtLeast(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))). If this was not the case, you'd never be able to find out that your job has succeeded, failed, or been cancelled.

As per the [`pruneWork()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#pruneWork()):

> You do not normally need to call this method - WorkManager takes care to auto-prune its work after a sane period of time

Where 'a sane period of time', according to [the source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:work/work-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/WorkDatabase.kt;l=177?q=PRUNE_THRESHOLD_MILLIS%20&ss=androidx) is currently set to 1 day (previously 7 days).